# Cant Find Android under Eclipse/Preference

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt, eclipse-adt

I downloaded Indigo Eclipse and installed the ADT from Eclipse Marketplace but its not showing up in the Eclipse/Preference plugin list.

I also tried removing the ADT from eclipse and the software site "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" from "available software sites" and then reinstalled the ADT from "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" using help->install new software. The installation was successful, but I still don't have any option for shortcuts to the SDK manager or the AVD in eclipse, and neither can I create a new android project.

By the way, when i check on the available software then its showing the ADT installed.

I also checked under:

- Window > Custom Perspective (you will see Android and AVD Manager were disable)
- Command Groups Availability > BUT CANT FIND Android SDK and AVD Manager

Also,  I Checked under

- Window -> show View -> other -> Plugin Development -> Plugin Registry
- In the plugin registry search for com.android.ide.eclipse.adt
- Select , Right Click -> Diagnose. 
  It shows the following problems were found:

  1. Missing required bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.base_0.0.0
  2. Missing required bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms_0.0.0

I DONT KNOW WHAT IS ABOVE REQUIREMENT OR I AM MISSING SOMETHING, Any IDEA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to follow these instructions:

[Here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html)

You need to have downloaded  Android SDK Tools and then follow the above instructions

Then,

[Install Elcipse Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

If you follow these steps exactly and it still doesn't work I would try uninstalling the IDE and starting from scratch.

Comment: Thankx guys! Actually i was running on java 1.5 and i had to update it to 1.6 to support the ADT 21.0. It works fine now. I also have to install Android SDK Tools. :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do, is to install the Android Developer Tools (ADT) which includes a customised version of Eclipse which also contains the SDK for Android Development.

You will in this manner avoid the issues you are currently experiencing.

You can find the link below:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html